# how to re-render the part of the react component that depends on the Map in its State

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends Component {

this.state = {      
  myMap: new Map()
};
```

when updating the Map...

```
{this.state.myMap.forEach((value, key, map) =>  {   
            console.log(key) 
            return <tr>
              <span>{key}</span>
```

`console.log(key)`     logging ok
`<span>{key}</span>`  //not rendering

Comment: forEach doesn't *return* anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `map` not `forEach`

```
myMap = new Map([["key1", 1], ["key2", 2], ["key3", 3]]);

{ [...this.state.myMap].map(item => {
   return <tr>
        <span>{item[0]}</span>
```